# I have a sorted array of n distinct elements. Find all the pair of elements a and b such that a+b>1000

Tags: algorithm

The best algorithm for this needs to be found out.
I have considered iterating over the entire array and for each element a[i], iterating again over the array to find an element that satisfies the condition. But, surely there is a better way

Comment: Ok. that's nice. Good luck with your homework. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions. it is not a "do my homework for me" service.

Comment: Well, I came across this question on some site and have been trying to find the solution since

Answer (score 1):

Since the array is sorted increasingly you can use binary search to find these pairs. Assume you want to find pairs which their sum is bigger than K. For each element `x` you can binary search for `K-x` and find its position `i` in the array. All the elements with indices more than `i` will make a pair with `x` which its sum is bigger than `K`.

Comment: Just use (binary) search to find the first number greater than 500: _every pair above_ will do. For the rest, _walk_ up and down from there. You "need" to search for the complement on 1001 when the sum drops below, only. [Galloping search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) may be a better fit than binary.